# Restart animated GIF as background-image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image, animated-gif

Is it possible to restart an animated GIF used as `background-image`?

Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="face">
    <div id="eyes"></eyes>
</div>
```

And this style:

```
#eyes.blink {
    background-image:url('blink.gif');
}
```

I would like the `blink.gif` animation to play every time I add the class `blink` to `#eyes`, not just the first time.

I expected this to work:

```
function startBlink() {
    $('#eyes').addClass('blink');
}

function stopBlink() {
    $('#eyes').removeClass('blink');
}
```

The problem is that both Firefox and WebKit browser do not play a background-image GIF animation again once it has played once. Adding/removing the class blink only works the first time.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Only if they've been set to loop.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim — they *can* do, it depends on the loop option being set inside the image.

Comment: @Noufal Yes, but I don't want a loop. I want to restart the animation when the user performs a certain event.

Comment: In 2016, I've been able to get this to work as a background-image just by resetting the source (or switching it between two images) in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox or Edge. They will still only display the last frame of a non-looping animation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the animated gif to replay by reloading it.  This isn't ideal for bandwidth, especially if your image is large, but it will force a restart of the animation.

In my example I'm adding and removing it `onclick` of `<div id="animated">`:

```
$('#animated').click(function() {

    /* Reference to the clicked element and toggle the .go class */
    var $div = $(this);
    $div.toggleClass('go');

    /* Start the animated gif */
    if ($div.hasClass('go')) {

        /* Create an <img> element and give it the animated gif as a src.  To 
           force a reload we add a date parameter to the URL */
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "http://yoursite.com/animated.gif?p" + new Date().getTime();

        /* Once the image has loaded, set it as the background-image */
        $(img).load(function(){
            $div.css({backgroundImage: "url("+img.src+")"});
        });

    /* Remove the background-image */        
    } else {
       $div.css({backgroundImage: "none"});
    }
})
```

[Demo of it](http://jsfiddle.net/64fZa/5/) in action.

Comment: why you add random number to file path ? to **lag** ? - simply resetting `src` is enough for animation restart. http://jsfiddle.net/Lqx2V/

Comment: @c69 it's to force it to not use the browser cache.  Without this Webkit wasn't restarting the animation.

Comment: It should be noted that $eyes.css('background-image', 'url(' + 'blink.gif?d=' + new Date().getTime() + ')'); is enough. No need to use an auxiliary img.

Comment: I simply added '#' + Math.random() to the URL, and it restarted the animation while using cache. Tested with Chrome 38.0.2125.111

Comment: '#' + Math.random() fails with Chrome 42.0.2311.135, but '?' + Math.random() works :-(

Answer (score 7):

I've found you can also add a `?+Math.random()` to the end of the picture src and it'll reload the .gif.

Comment: Even better, you can add '#' + Math.random() to the URL, and then presumably the browser doesn't have to reload it. I have tested this in Chrome, and it works (it is retrieved from cache).

Comment: @Abram, adding `#` to the URL instead of `?` doesn't seem to work anymore FWIW

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative that does not reload the GIF every time and waste bandwidth.

It involves storing the GIF as Base64 in memory (circumventing browser cache), and uses the FileReader API (which seems to be [supported in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader)). Note that loading images this way is subject to cross-origin policy (unlike the image reload solutions.)

**Update:** Browser caching is getting smarter about caching background image data URI's, causing the animation not to start over. I found I had to add a cache-busting random string to the data url now (which according to the [DataURI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), should be considered an optional attribute. Tested in Chrome & IE Edge.)

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jcward/nknLrtzL/10/

Here's how it works. This function loads the image as a Base64-encoded string.

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // IE11, set responseType must come after .open()
  xhr.send();
}
```

Then, any time you want to restart the GIF animation, change the `background-image` property to `none`, then the base64 string (in some browsers, you need to re-add the child to trigger the update without a setTimeout):

```
$div.css({backgroundImage: "none"});
$div.parent().add($div); // Some browsers need this to restart the anim
// Slip in a cache busting random number to the data URI attributes
$div.css({backgroundImage: "url("+img_base64.replace("image/gif","image/gif;rnd="+Math.random())+")"});
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) for the `toDataURL` function (with fix for IE11.)

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 3):

I combined several parts of the solution to make one whole solution that solves (hopefully) all problems:

- Determine the background-image URL of an element (from css `background-image`)
- Trigger a restart for that image WITHOUT reloading it from the web
- Restarting it in all places (without touching each individually)
- Making sure the target is repainted without artifacts after restarting the animation

In my solution i create helper images that are added to the body but hidden in a way so they are still rendered by the browser but won't interact with the page visually using `position: absolute; left: -5000px;`.

A reference to our helper images is cached in `resetHelperImages` so we can reuse them for the same image in subsequent calls.

I am using jQuery for my example, but it could be adapted to work without jQuery, too.

Tested in: Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.130 m)

```js
var resetHelperImages = {};

function restartAnimation(elem) {
  elem = $(elem);
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var element = elem[i];
    // code part from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14013171/1520422
    var style = element.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(element, false);
    // var bgImg = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, '');
    var bgImg = style.backgroundImage.match(/url\(([^\)]+)\)/)[1].replace(/"/g, '');
    // edit: Suggestion from user71738 to handle background-images with additional settings

    var helper = resetHelperImages[bgImg]; // we cache our image instances
    if (!helper) {
      helper = $('<img>')
        .attr('src', bgImg)
        .css({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: '-5000px'
        }) // make it invisible, but still force the browser to render / load it
        .appendTo('body')[0];
      resetHelperImages[bgImg] = helper;
      setTimeout(function() {
        helper.src = bgImg;
      }, 10);
      // the first call does not seem to work immediately (like the rest, when called later)
      // i tried different delays: 0 & 1 don't work. With 10 or 100 it was ok.
      // But maybe it depends on the image download time.
    } else {
      // code part from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21012986/1520422
      helper.src = bgImg;
    }
  }
  // force repaint - otherwise it has weird artefacts (in chrome at least)
  // code part from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29946331/1520422
  elem.css("opacity", .99);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.css("opacity", 1);
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
.myBgImageClass {
  background-image: url('http://i410.photobucket.com/albums/pp184/OllieMarchant/Countup.gif');
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myBgImageClass"></div>
<button onclick="restartAnimation($('.myBgImageClass'))">restart</button>
```

Comment: @jnkb yes, you are right, it does not work in IE. Maybe a general solution for all browsers would be to download and cache the raw data of the image and then create a `data:`-url from it to restart the animation. Maybe `data:`-url with cache invalidation ... is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the same image twice called blink.gif and blink2.gif, adding two classes for them and toggling between classes?

```
<div id="face">
    <div id="eyes"></eyes>
</div>

.blink {
    background-image:url('blink.gif');
}

.blink2 {
    background-image:url('blink2.gif');
}

function MakeBlink()
{
   if ($('#eyes').hasClass('blink'))
   {
      $('#eyes').removeClass('blink').addClass('blink2');
   } else
   {
     $('#eyes').removeClass('blink2').addClass('blink');
   }
}
```

Comment: This would be the way to go for a two-frames animation ("blink"). Gif animations can be cancelled by hitting the Esc button on the keyboard.

Comment: Is there really a need to have a different image? I can't see the reason why *$('#eyes').removeClass('blink').addClass('blink');* wouldn't work

Comment: @Ivan — Presumably the OP wants the eyes to blink by having the eyelids shut, and not by disappearing.

Comment: Well in this case it's even better to use the same image. If blink2.gif is not preloaded then background will disappear for considerable time. If we use the same image then it's just a matter of removing and adding same class which should take same amount of time as removing and applying a different class sans loading a new image.

Comment: I would advise preloading blink2.gif but they should be different names to make sure the browser does not assume there has been no style change and therefore skip the animation

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately this doesn't work. From the third time MakeBlink is executed the GIF animations do not play anymore (basically, it exhibits the same behavior than with 1 GIF).

Comment: @Ivan The problem is that both Firefox and WebKit browser do not play a background-image GIF animation again once it has played once. Adding/removing the class blink will only work once.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I still need this every now and then I figured the pure JS function I use might be helpful for someone else.  This is a pure JS way of restarting an animated gif, without reloading it.   You can call this from a link and/or document load event.

```
<img id="img3" src="../_Images/animated.gif">

<a onClick="resetGif('img3')">reset gif3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

// reset an animated gif to start at first image without reloading it from server.
// Note: if you have the same image on the page more than ones, they all reset.
function resetGif(id) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    var imageUrl = img.src;
    img.src = "";
    img.src = imageUrl;
};

</script>
```

On some browsers you only need to reset the img.src to itself and it works fine.  On IE you need to clear it before resetting it.  This resetGif() picks the image name from the image id.  This is handy in case you ever change the actual image link for a given id because you do not have to remember to change the resetGiF() calls.

--Nico

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this works:

```
// Append the image to the page
var i = new Image();
i.src = 'some.gif';
document.body.appendChild(i);

// Now execute this line and the gif will restart
// (anywhere it appears on the page, including CSS backgrounds)
i.src = 'some.gif';
```

This requires an actual image DOM element to be appended to the page, but you can hide it with `visibility: hidden`.  This *doesn't* require the image to be downloaded over the network multiple times.

I only tested this in Firefox and Chrome.  Not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093916) posted by [Frederic Leitenberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520422/frederic-leitenberger), I found it to work wonderfully.

However, it breaks down if your background-image has multiple, layered parts, like this:

```
background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at center,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%);
```

To get around this limitation, I modified the line that finds the background image url, like so:

```
var bgImg = style.backgroundImage.match(/url\(([^\)]+)\)/)[1].replace(/"/g, '');
```

This uses a regular expression to extract just the URL portion of the background-image.

I would have added this as a comment to the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093916), but I'm a noob without reputation, so was blocked from doing so. Those with adequate rep may want to add the line to the actual answer.

Comment: I added your improvement to my solution. Thanks!