# Proper way to reset a GIF animation with display:none on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, animated-gif

Title is self-explanatory, but I'll provide a step-by-step view on the matter. Hopefully I'm not the first one to have noticed this (apparently) bug on Webkit/Chrome.

I want to reset a GIF animation. All of the examples I've seen so far either simply set the `src` of the image to itself or set it to an empty string followed by the original `src` again.

Take a look at this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Fuy9w/3/)** for reference. The GIF resets perfectly fine on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

The issue which I have is when the image has `display:none` on **Google Chrome only**.

Check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/F8Q44/3/)**.  The GIF resets fine on IE and Firefox before being displayed in the page, but Chrome simply refuses to reset its animation!

**What I've tried so far:**

- Setting the `src` to itself as in Fiddle, doesn't work in Chrome.
- Setting the `src` to an empty string and restoring it to the default, doesn't work either.
- Putting an wrapper around the image, emptying the container through `.html('')` and putting the image back inside of it, doesn't work either.
- Changing the `display` of the image through `.show()` or `.fadeIn()` right before setting the `src` doesn't work either.

The **only** workaround which I've found so far is keeping the image with its default `display` and manipulating it through `.animate()`ing and `.css()`ing the opacity, height and visibility when necessary to simulate a `display:none` behaviour.

The main reason (context) of this question is that I wanted to reset an ajax loader GIF right before fading it in the page.

So my question is, is there a proper way to reset a GIF image's animation (which avoids Chrome's `display:none` "bug") or is it actually a bug?

(ps. You may change the GIF in the fiddles for a more appropriate/longer animation gif for testing)

Comment: I worked out a complete solution. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31093916/1520422

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Chrome deals with style changes differently than other browsers.

In Chrome, when you call `.show()` with no argument, the element is not actually shown immediately right where you call it. Instead, Chrome *queues* the application of the new style for execution *after* evaluating the current chunk of JavaScript; whereas other browsers would apply the new style change immediately. `.attr()`, however, does not get queued. So you are effectively trying to set the `src` when the element is still not visible according to Chrome, and Chrome won't do anything about it when the original `src` and new `src` are the same.

Instead, what you need to do is to make sure jQuery sets the `src` *after* `display:block` is applied. You can make use of `setTimeout` to achieve this effect:

```
var src = 'http://i.imgur.com/JfkmXjG.gif';
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $img = $('img');
    $('#target').toggle(
        function(){
            var timeout = 0; // no delay
            $img.show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $img.attr('src', src);
            }, timeout);
        },
        function(){
            $img.hide();
        }
    );
});
```

This ensures that `src` is set *after* `display:block` has been applied to the element.

The reason this works is because setTimeout queues the function for execution *later* (however long *later* is), so the function is no longer considered to be part of the current "chunk" of JavaScript, and it provides a gap for Chrome to render and apply the `display:block` first, thus making the element visible before its `src` attribute is set.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F8Q44/19/

Thanks to shoky in #jquery of freenode IRC for providing a simpler answer.

---

Alternatively, you can force a redraw to flush the batched style changes. This can be done, for example, by accessing the element's `offsetHeight` property:

```
$('img').show().each(function() {
    this.offsetHeight;
}).prop('src', 'image src');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F8Q44/266/

Comment: Better late than never, thank you! I understand how browsers batch up style changes, but never considered it'd apply in this use case. I'll experiment a little bit now. +1 for the useful info

Comment: I've edited your answer to add the alternative which I'd use in a real scenario so I can accept your answer instead of submitting my own answer. Thanks.

Comment: How can I use this to reset a gif that's set as a css background image and not a SRC? Example: http://bit.ly/1XKm8JC - The image works fine on first play, but after the animation ends and it goes back to the start the Seasons Greetings gif doesn't start over. I'm using Edge Animate

Comment: `$('img').prop('src',function(){return this.src;})` is the minimal version of this answer

Comment: Large timeout values (>500ms) seem to be required to get MS Edge to act reliably

Answer (score 33):

The most reliable way to "reset" a GIF is by appending a random query string. However this does mean that the GIF will be redownloaded every time so make sure it's a small file.

```
// reset a gif:
img.src = img.src.replace(/\?.*$/,"")+"?x="+Math.random();
```

Comment: +1 as it actually "fixes" the issue in chrome, even though requesting a new image download right before displaying it goes against my initial concept of already having it cached in the page. I'll keep the question open a little longer to check if there aren't any other possible solutions, as for now I'd keep my fake `display:none` behavior.

Comment: Where does this code go? I'd love to see a working version with jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks for the great solution Niet. This is my version of it for `background-image` (it does require jQuery though): `img.css('background-image', img.css('background-image').replace(".gif", ".gif" + "?x=" + Math.random()));`

Comment: `img.src=img.src` seems enough for me (am using Chrome 48). can anyone confirm with other browsers?

Comment: I am down voting this answer because this causes one of the internet's biggest image formats to get downloaded over and over again.

Comment: @ConnorRoss Let us examine that statement for a moment, if you don't mind. It's extremely good at what it does, when done correctly. That being said, the answer explicitly states to make sure it's a small file.

Answer (score 5):

This seemed to work for me in Chrome, it runs each time just before I fade in the image and clears then refills the src and my animation now starts from the beginning every time.

```
var imgsrc = $('#my_image').attr('src');
$('#my_image').attr('src', '');
$('#my_image').attr('src', imgsrc);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just because I still need this every now and then I figured the pure JS function I use might be helpful for someone else.  This is a pure JS way of restarting an animated gif, without reloading it.   You can call this from a link and/or document load event.

```
<img id="img3" src="../_Images/animated.gif">

<a onClick="resetGif('img3')">reset gif3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

// reset an animated gif to start at first image without reloading it from server.
// Note: if you have the same image on the page more than ones, they all reset.
function resetGif(id) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    var imageUrl = img.src;
    img.src = "";
    img.src = imageUrl;
};

</script>
```

On some browsers you only need to reset the img.src to itself and it works fine.  On IE you need to clear it before resetting it.  This resetGif() picks the image name from the image id.  This is handy in case you ever change the actual image link for a given id because you do not have to remember to change the resetGiF() calls.

--Nico

Comment: This function works perfect.
The only thing I had to change to make it equally work on chrome:
 `img.src = "#";`

The restart if the first src is completely empty.

Answer (score 4):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191922/restart-an-animated-gif-from-javascript-without-reloading-the-image) preloads the gif and takes it out of the dom and then back in the src (thus avoiding another download)

I just tested it using jquery to remove the attribute and it works fine.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

$(function() {

    $('.reset').click(resetGif);

    function resetGif() 
    {
        $('.img1').removeAttr('src', '');
    }
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <img class="img1" src="1.gif" />
    <a href="#" class="reset">reset gif</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Reset gif animation

When the browser render `img`, the source specified in `src` attribute is cached into memory for future reuse. This allows to increase the speed of page loading/reloading, as well as reduce the load on the network. And this behavior suits mostly everyone, because in reality, this is the most optimal and demanded option.

However, as always, there are exceptions. I came up with a dataUrl-based animation update option that solves several problems.

### Issues solved:

1. Need to display **gif** images with animation without a loop (*loop = 1*), which may have the same `src`. But when one such picture appears, it is necessary that it play the animation without changing the animation of other pictures with the same `src`. The same picture should be loaded from server only once. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917982/how-can-you-instantiate-a-gif-file-in-a-react-app/68918284)
2. Reset gif animation.
3. Start animation on hover

### Reset src attribute

If we use a solution that clears the `src` attribute of an image, then all images with the same source will replay their animation. Unfortunately, I still did not fully understand why this is happening, but it interferes with correct work.

#### Cons

- Reset animation of all images with the same src.
- There are [problems in mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831319/restart-a-gif-animation-without-reloading-the-file#comment118113914_24810221)

#### Pros

- Easy and fast

### Modify url with random query

This solution consists in adding a random query parameter to the end of the `src` attribute, so that all images will have a different source, and therefore they will animate independently of each other. There is one big fat **NO**: this will lead to a constant request to the server to download the picture, and therefore they will no longer be cached. And if we need to display 100 identical pictures, then there will be 100 requests to the server. Rough and tough, but it always works.

#### Cons

- Each picture with a unique query will be reloaded from the server.

#### Pros

- Easy and fast

### Modify dataUrl (Proposed Solution)

> Data URLs, URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents. They were formerly known as "data URIs" until that name was retired by the WHATWG.
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

The dataUrl structure from this documentation:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

And this is how it is indicated in the [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397):

```
dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
mediatype  := [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
data       := *urlchar
parameter  := attribute "=" value
```

If you look closely at the description of `mediatype`, then some strange `parameter` is indicated there. But, there is also a [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045#section-5.1):

```
     attribute := token
                  ; Matching of attributes
                  ; is ALWAYS case-insensitive.

     value := token / quoted-string

     token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs, or tspecials>

     tspecials :=  "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" /
                   "," / ";" / ":" / "\" / <">
                   "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "="
                   ; Must be in quoted-string,
                   ; to use within parameter values
```

As can be seen, we can specify any parameter, the main thing is that it meets the requirements presented above!
Therefore, we can embed an additional attribute in the mediatype, which will not affect the image in any way, but the data url will differ from the same image.

#### Generalized algorithm:

1. We load the image through a regular request and remove the metadata from created dataUrl from blob.

```js
fetch("https://cdn140.picsart.com/330970106009201.gif").then(async (res) => {
  const blob = await res.blob();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (ev) => {
    // It would be reasonable to remove metadata to the point!
    // But for simplicity, I'm using this implementation.
    const dataUrl = ev.currentTarget.result.replace(
      "data:image/gif;base64",
      ""
    );
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

2. Create/edit `img` element with `src` attribute `"src=data:image/gif;base64;${Math.random()}${dataUrl}"`
3. That is all!

#### Example Vanila JS

```js
const url = "https://cdn140.picsart.com/330970106009201.gif";

function loadImage(src) {
  fetch(src)
    .then((res) => res.blob())
    .then(async(blob) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (ev) => {
        const dataUrl = ev.currentTarget.result.replace("data:image/gif;base64", "")
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        while (container.firstChild) {
          container.firstChild.remove()
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          const img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("src", `data:image/gif;base64;gif-id=${Date.now()}${dataUrl}`)
          container.appendChild(img);
          img.addEventListener('click', ev => {
            img.setAttribute("src", `data:image/gif;base64;gif-id=${Date.now()}${dataUrl}`)
          })
        }
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
}

loadImage(url);

function updateImage() {
  const newSrc = document.getElementById("image-src");
  loadImage(document.getElementById("image-src").value);
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <label>Change gif url if current will become unavailable </label>
  <input id="image-src" value="https://cdn140.picsart.com/330970106009201.gif"></input>
  <button onclick="updateImage()">Update image source attribute</button>
  <span>Click to reset!</span>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example React

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const [stars, setStars] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const ref = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://cdn140.picsart.com/330970106009201.gif")
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then(async (text) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (ev) => {
          setData(ev.currentTarget.result.replace("data:image/gif;base64", ""));
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(text);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => s + 1)}>+</p>
      {data &&
        new Array(stars).fill().map((s, ind) => {
          return <Star src={data} key={ind}></Star>;
        })}
      <p onClick={() => setStars((s) => (s === 0 ? 0 : s - 1))}>-</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export function Star(props) {
  const [id] = useState(Math.random());

  return (
    <img
      className="icon"
      src={`data:image/gif;base64;gif-id=${id}` + props.src}
      alt="animated star"
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've a button with the an animated no-loop image in it. I just reload the image with some jquery and this seems to be working for me.

```
var asdf = $(".settings-button img").attr("src");
$(".settings-button img").attr("src", "").attr("src", asdf);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's my hack for background images:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.logo', function() {
  window.logo = (window.logocount || 0) + 1;
  var img = new Image();
  var url = "/img/mylogimagename.gif?v=" + window.logocount;
var that = this;
  $(img).load(function(){

     $(that ).css('background-image','url(' + url + ')');
  });
  img.src = url;
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide some details on what variables need to be changed to use this. I know the var url does, but but else?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced problems with all of the above solutions.  What finally worked was replacing the src temporarily with a transparent 1px gif:

```
var transparent1PxGif = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7';
var reloadGif = function(img) {
    var src = img.src;
    img.src = transparent1PxGif;
    img.offsetHeight; // triggers browser redraw
    img.src = src;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been several years and I've decided to revisit this since we have a number of new options at our disposal.

The issue with [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730240/507674) is that it forces a re-download of the GIF every single time you want to re-start it. While that's fine for small files, it's still an overhead that's best avoided if possible.

With that in mind, I've got a new solution that uses AJAX to download the GIF once, and then converts it into a data URL (via a FileReader) and uses that as the source with a random query string attached.

This way, the browser only ever downloads the image once, and can even cache it properly, and the "reset" pulls from that pre-downloaded resource.

The only catch, of course, is that you have to make sure it's properly loaded before you can use it.

Demo: http://adamhaskell.net/misc/numbers/numbers.html

Relevant code:

```
var url = "something.gif"; // fallback until the FileReader is done
function setup() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( this.readyState == 4) {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function() {
                url = this.result; // overwrite URL with the data one
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(this.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
function getGIF() {
    return url+"?x="+Math.random();
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is that there is no support for query strings in `data:` URLs so what you're doing here is adding meaningless unencoded data to the end of the base64-encoded GIF data that the browser renders. I'm guessing it works because the browser's GIF renderer simply ignores the extra data.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread after searching many others. David Bell's post led me to the solution I needed.

I thought I'd post my experience in the event that it could be useful for anyone trying to accomplish what I was after. This is for an HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery web app that will be an iPhone app via PhoneGap. Testing in Chrome.

**The Goal:**

1. When user taps/clicks button A, an animated gif appears and plays.
2. When user taps/clicks button B, gif disappears.
3. When user taps/clicks button A again, after tapping/clicking button
   B, animated gif should reappear and play from the beginning.

**The Problem:**

- On tap/click of button A, I was appending the gif to an existing div. It would play fine.
- Then, on tap/click of button B, I was hiding the container div, then setting the img src of the gif to an empty string (''). Again, no problem (that is, the problem wasn't evident yet.)
- **Then, on tap/click of button A, after tap/click of button B, I was re-adding the path to the gif as the src.**

  *- **This did not work.** The gif would show up on subsequent taps/clicks of button A...however, the more I tapped/clicked button A, the more times the gif would load and start over. That is, if I went back and forth, tapping/clicking button A then button B 3 times, the gif would appear and then start/stop/start 3 times...and my whole app started to chug. I guess the gif was being loaded multiple times, even though I had set the src to an empty string when button B was tapped/clicked.*

**The Solution:**

After looking at David Bell's post, I arrived at my answer.

1. I defined a global variable (let's call it myVar) that held the container div and the image (with the source path) within.
2. On the tap/click function of button A, I appended that container div to an existing parent div in the dom.
3. In that function, I created a new variable that holds the src path of the gif.

Just like David suggested, I did this (plus an append):

```
$('#mainParent').append(myVar);
var imgsrc = $('#my_image').attr('src');
$('#my_image').attr('src', '');
$('#my_image').attr('src', imgsrc);
```

THEN, in the function for button B, I set the src to an empty string and then removed the div containing the gif:

```
$('#my_image').attr('src', '');
$('#mainParent').find('#my_image').remove();
```

Now, I can tap/click button A then button B then button A, etc., all day long. The gif loads and plays on tap/click of button A, then hides on tap/click of button B, then loads and plays from the beginning on subsequent taps of button A every time with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a complete solution for this problem. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31093916/1520422

My solution restarts the animation WITHOUT re-loading the image data from the network.

It also enforces the image to repaint to fix some painting artefacts that occured (in chrome).