# GIF restarts in browser normally, but not on my site after using show()/hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

I want to create an image and then have a gif play after it, repeating indefinitely.  When I link to this [GIF](http://assets0.ordienetworks.com/misc/rambo%20rambo.gif) it loops just fine in my browser.  However, when I toggle its display with show()/hide():

```
var pics = $('.slider');
function autoSlideIn() {
    if (index > pics.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    $(pics[index]).show();
    setTimeout("autoSlideOut()", duration);
}

function autoSlideOut() {
    if (index > pics.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    $(pics[index]).hide();
    index++;
    autoSlideIn();
}

<img class="slider" src="www.image.com/picture.png"/>
<img class="slider" src="www.gifdontwork.com/gif.gif"/>
```

Instead, the GIF will play only once and then be stuck on a single frame and never restart despite it repeating normally.  How can I restart it without reloading the image?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here, you have an array called "pics" but no reference to it here. Can you also supply some markup?

Comment: Updated with sample markup.  as I stated, it will cycle between the two pictures just fine, but the GIF will not continue repeating after being hidden.

Comment: I believe this is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730212/proper-way-to-reset-a-gif-animation-with-displaynone-on-chrome you will need to put a revision number at the end so that the browser doesn't cache it, this will force it to re-download the gif every time, so buyer beware.

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't be the only way to do it since the gif refreshes normally in my browser and i'd like to avoid unnecessary network use.