# Animated GIF Repeat iOS 8

Tags: javascript, ios, ios8, gif, animated-gif

I think there is a bug in iOS 8 which prevents animated GIFs from repeating, even if they are supposed to do so.

I have tried setting the source to nothing, then adding the file name back in, but it does not seem to repeat.

```
document.getElementById("img").src = "";
document.getElementById("img").src = "animated.gif";
```

Is there a more modern way to reset GIFs than said in this post: [Proper way to reset a GIF animation with display:none on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730212/proper-way-to-reset-a-gif-animation-with-displaynone-on-chrome)?

Thanks.

Comment: To confirm - I've seen this too, at least in the UIWebView in iOS 8. I haven't tested in pure Safari.

Comment: @JamieBrown I think it exists in both the webview and Safari.

Comment: It's not an answer, but since it's thrown an unexpected spanner in the works for my Cordova-powered app, I'm migrating my spinner GIF to a sprite, animated by JavaScript.