# base64 encoded animated gif as css background?

Tags: jquery, css, animated-gif

I have an animated gif encoded into my css as such:

```
.magicBg {
background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQBkAPcAAAAAAAEBAQICAgMDAwQEBAUFBQYGBgcHBwgICAkJCQoKCgsLCwwMDA0ND ...
}
```

This animated gif is encoded to play once.

However, once this animated gif plays once as background on an element, it never plays again.  Using

```
$('body').removeClass( 'magicBg' );
$('body').addClass( 'magicBg' )
```

Has no effect -- we start on the final frame of the gif.  Any ideas how to make this play from the beginning every time the class is added?

Unfortunately, [another answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568855/restart-animated-gif-as-background-image) reloading the gif from the server using some random url parameters.  Alas, this is not going to work for my case as I am encoding the image into the css itself.  Can you add a random date stamp to base64 data?

Comment: I thought that forcing the browser to redraw would do it, but it seems not. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RichardTowers/nfajy/).

Comment: The image appears to have been broken during encoding or was simply saved as the kind that doesn't loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add additional bogus fields to the data url to force replaying of the animated gif:

```
//use date timestamp to ensure no duplicates
url(data:image/gif;bogus:ABCDEF;base64,R0lGODlhA...);
```

Comment: I just discovered that this will not work in IE unless you replace the colon with an equals sign.
e.g. url(data:image/gif;bogus=ABCDEF;base64,R0lGODlhA...);

Answer (score 3):

Glad to see the trend of embedding `base64`-encoded *loading gifs* is taking off!

Back to the issue at hand, there`s a pretty common typo in your background declaration, [fixed that for you](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/nfajy/16/). The following:

<del>`base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAOMAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkv/////////////////////...`</del>

should have been instead

`base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAP///wAAAMLCwkJCQgAAAGJiYoKCgpKSkiH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwE...`

Seriously though, you've probably just encoded a corrupted file (not impossible if you were using an online encoding tool).

To troubleshoot the issue, I've first downloaded the file you've embedded (*right click > view background image > right click > save as...* on Firefox). That image could not render correctly either: [image: doesn't "spin"!]

Funny enough, it looked just fine in Finder file preview when I was uploading it to [SO imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WkLY.gif). Broken index? File upload terminated too soon? I don't know enough about technicalities of the  GIF format to offer insight beyond speculation, but I've encoded the fixed file.

**NB:** no need to use quotes in `url()`