# Freezes in CSS animations when rendering DOM

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, safari

I do web chat, if there are a lot of messages and pictures in the dialog, then when I open it with a cache, it starts to slow down the browser and CSS animation, if I open a dialog without a cache and that's it, the history every time loads again, the animations work smoothly.

The fact is that when loading a story from the cache, the animation starts simultaneously with the DOM rendering. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing your code.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a very similar problem with Promise, but it doesn't work.

Comment: maybe help somehow separate to another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206587/1347601

Comment: Did you found solution?