# How to get background image URL of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

How would I get the `background-image` URL of a `<div>` element in JavaScript?
For example, I have this:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>
```

How would I get **just** the URL of the `background-image`?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('your_div_id'),
style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

```js
// Get the image id, style and the url from it
var img = document.getElementById('testdiv'),
  style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
  bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");

// Display the url to the user
console.log('Image URL: ' + bi);
```

```html
<div id="testdiv" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200');"></div>
```

**Edit:**

Based on @Miguel and other comments below, you can try this to remove additional quotation marks if your browser (IE/FF/Chrome...) adds it to the url:

```
bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

and if it may includes single quotation, use: `replace(/['"]/g, "")`

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3c6ymrpo/)**

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work on IE as the string returned is quoted. so I ended up with this:
`bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");`

And now works :)

Comment: Firefox quotes the strings too. At least as of FF39.

Comment: `style.backgroundImage.slice(5, -2)` works too of course.

Comment: slice?? I feel like a medieval peasant

Comment: This is great and answer's OP's question 9 years ago, but be aware that it won't work if `backgroundImage` has a `linear-gradient`; e.g.: `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)), url(https://my.image.com);`

Answer (score 26):

Just to add to this in case anyone else has a similar idea, you could also use Regex:

```
var url = backgroundImage.match(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/)[1];
```

However it seems like @Praveen's solution actually performs better in Safari and Firefox, according to jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/match-vs-slice-and-replace

If you want to account for cases where the value includes quotes but are unsure whether it's a double or single quote, you could do:

```
var url = backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Comment: this is complete answer

Comment: the `|` is unrequired in your regex, the `[...]` means any of chars inside. `replace(/["']/g, "")` is ok

Answer (score 15):

**Try this:**

```
var url = document.getElementById("divID").style.backgroundImage;
alert(url.substring(4, url.length-1));
```

**Or, using `replace`:**

```
backgroundImage.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/["']/g, "");
// Or...
backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Comment: This substring just removes the `url(`. It doesn't remove the quotes. The replace won't work for double quotes. Using the substring _and_ the replace is okay, but won't handle double quotes. `backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/["']/g, "");` is what you're looking for

Comment: @narthur157 agreed and updated, but this is a 7 year old answer. 

Comment: Any more update is needed? Or is it good as it looks? @jave.web Happy to update more. Or go ahead and please update.

Comment: @jave.web Just edit the answer, I'll approve it and you will get some points too! 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman ok, since people are still looking to this answer even now-adays - I've done the edit :)

Answer (score 9):

First of all you need to return your background-image content:

```
var img = $('#your_div_id').css('background-image');
```

This will return the URL as following:

"url('http://www.example.com/img.png')"

Then you need to remove the un-wanted parts of this URL:

```
img = img.replace(/(url\(|\)|")/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /background-image:url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/gm;
const str = `<div style="background-image:url('http://www.example.com/img.png');">...</div>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Log to console all `background-image` URLs, without parentheses and quotes:

```
var element = document.getElementById('divId');
var prop = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('background-image');
var re = /url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi;
var matches;
while ((matches = re.exec(prop)) !== null) {
    console.log(matches[2]);
}
```