# how to fetch `style="background-image: url` using selenium webDrive?

Tags: android, css, selenium

I grabbed this element using selenium webDrive:

```
<div class="body" style="background-image: url('http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_619_o_6042_precious_image_1419849753.png');">
```

how can I fetch the value: `http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_619_o_6042_precious_image_1419849753.png` ?

I'm not sure as this is an inner value, and not just an "src" attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div

Comment: I hope you are looking selenium-java combination answer.please remove the javascript tag people are answering in javascript

Answer (score 7):

getCssValue(); will help you

```
 WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.className('body'));
 String imgpath = img.getCssValue("background-image");
```

then you can split the unwanted string "url('"

PS : Remove the javascript tag in your question

Comment: how can I fetch with regex the url itself? `url('http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_619_o_6042_precious_image_1419849753.png');">`

Comment: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/ this may help you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var imgString = $(".body").css('background-image');
console.log (imgString.split("(")[1] // remove open bracket
                      .split(")")[0] // remove close bracket
             );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1so2qndf/1/)

Comment: v=element(By.css('.icon.delete'));   

v.getCssValue("background-image").then (x) ->

   console.log x

Comment: what language is this? I didn't get ??

Comment: I am giving the answer in the way of jquery

Comment: this is not suitable for your question

Comment: @ji-ruh - The OP tagged javascript on time of posting the question. SO i answered in javascript, Yup later he untag the javascript \

Comment: Im using protractor and coffeescipt.

Comment: here is the exact error: ypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'split'

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
some_variable=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='body' and contains(@style,'url')]")
some_variable2=some_variable.get_attribute('style')
```