# Javascript get wrong background-image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

I want to get the natural sizes of a image on my server but I dont get the real source of my image.

I do get the source of via jquery:

```
.css('background-image').replace('url(','').replace(')','');
```

But when I store this URL into img.src so it doesn't get the right image source.

What I get: http://vatocc.net/%22http://vatocc.net/function/file/get/get_file.php?file=/secure/user_img/background_img/1265024466.jpg&purpose=view&format=false%22

Real link: http://vatocc.net/function/file/get/get_file.php?file=/secure/user_img/background_img/1265024466.jpg&purpose=view&format=false

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7r5yu7ts/)

UPDATE:

https://jsfiddle.net/7r5yu7ts/1/

Comment: The link to the first image is broken.

Comment: You're not removing the quotes, that's why it doesn't work, and the URL is considered relative

Comment: You get `url("image.png")`, and after replacing you have `"image.png"`, with the quotes, so when you add it to the src property, it's considered being relative, not absolute.

Comment: You need to use `.css('background-image').replace('url("','').replace('")','');` to remove the double quotes

Comment: Thank you guys, I do get my fault so I will get one more coffee chears ^^

Comment: I was looking for this info but for plain JS, so how is it supposed to be inJS?
style.backgroundImage = url("image.png") ?
or style.backgroundImage = 'url("image.png")' ?

Comment: If you want to set a background image see here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage - If you want to get the url see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML

I want to do the following
if (firstGal.style.opacity == 0 && displayed.style.backgroundImage == ???)

I wanna know the exact syntax to go into the ??? placeholder.
If I use  variable from getComputedStyle, it kinda works, but the perfect solution would be knowing the exact syntax required, with url, just like you do.
Cheers:-)

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML
Nah, does not, this seems to be one of those typical cases where using jQuery just makes more sense. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var background = $('div').css('background-image'),
imgPath = background.substring(background.lastIndexOf("(")+2,background.lastIndexOf(")")-1);
```

Full working:

```
var background = $('div').css('background-image'),
    imgPath = background.substring(background.lastIndexOf("(")+2,background.lastIndexOf(")")-1);

var img = new Image;
    img.src = imgPath;
    $('i').html('Source: ' + img.src + 'Width: ' + img.width + ' Height: ' + img.height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7r5yu7ts/3/