# How to get css background-mage in new tab or popup in javasctipt

Tags: javascript, css

I want to fetch the background-image from this css how can i do it?

```
<div  class="zoomWindow" style="overflow: hidden; background-position: -174.967px -146.847px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 700px; height: 450px; float: left; background-size: 1100px 1500px; z-index: 100; border: 0px solid rgb(136, 136, 136); background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/detailed/45044/UX8A34631_1475562297.jpg&quot;); top: 200.4px; left: 623.5px; display: none;">&nbsp;</div>
```

my code open the new tab with url of background image BUT the domain name is still there i dont know why

Here is my code

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('zoomWindow');
console.log(img[0].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1));
var imagers =img[0].style.backgroundImage.slice(11, -2);
window.open(imagers);
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch it in Javascript variable..?

Comment: yes...........!

Comment: @bhavinshah the guy wants the background-image, not the src

Comment: @BhavinShah it is not in css property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Get background-image URL of <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div)

Comment: Just FYI, you can't use decimals in pixels. It is ineffective. Pixel values must be whole numbers

Comment: @Caelan. Thats not his code Or he works at Shopclues i dont know

Comment: @Riddler I don't know what you mean...

Comment: Did you ever find your answer?

Comment: @Caelan. hi yes i found but not completly i found that i can extract the bg property and open the url in new tab BUT the domain where it is coming from magically always getting there.. for example my url of image is cdn.com/image.jpg now when the new tab comes out with the url it become www.shopclues.com/cdn.com/image.jpg i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM:

```
document.getElementById('image_1').style.backgroundImage;
```

JQuery:

```
$('#image_1').css("background-image");
```

If you want just the url value, you will need to do one more thing, to strip the value `url(&quot;http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/detailed/45044/UX8A34631_1475562297.jpg&quot;)` of the `url()` function.

Comment: how to get only image in new tab or popup?

Comment: to pass the value to another page, there are several ways: you could pass it as a parameter in url or via a cookie or save the value to the server and then retireve from the other page. But, what exactly are you trying to do, would not just creating a css for the other page (using the value of the image url) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the value of the `background-image` property like so:

Pure **JavaScript**:

```
var imageSrc = document.getElementByClassName("zoomWindow");
var imageLocation = imageSrc.style.backgroundImage;
```

Or, if you have the **jQuery** library installed:

```
var imageLocation = $(".zoomWindow").css("background-image");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var one =$('.zoomWindow').css("background-image");
console.log(one);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have with the extraction of the URL applied:

```
$(function(){

  var $zoomWindow = $('.zoomWindow'),
      backgroundImage = $zoomWindow.css('background-image'),
      extraction = backgroundImage.match(/[^url('][^')]*/),
      url = extraction[0];

  console.log(url); // -> http://cdn.shopclues.com/images/detailed/45044/UX8A34631_1475562297.jpg

});
```

Comment: Follow this answer and just use window.open(url);