# Challenge JavaScript grab image URL from HTML class

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-parsing

**This question differs from other questions before, in that here we have a 
 STYLE inside a CLASS name. That made it a little more complicated to me.**

I want to alert() ONLY the url of a image showing in the website, that is accessible with its class name:

```
    <div  class='image-container-image' style="background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);">
</div>
```

I tried by doing:

```
alert( (document.querySelector('.image-container-image').textContent) );
```

Tried other different ways, but still no luck.

> My output should be an alert showing the following url:
>   "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg"

Your guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you "Challenge"-ing us on Stack Overflow? Or did someone "Challenge" you?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013171) may be able to help you.

Comment: Could you include the different ways to tried to achieve the desired result ? I'm positive some regex could probably solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Get background-image URL of <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/javascript-get-background-image-url-of-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>121</s> 89 bytes

One-liner, code-golf style:

```js
alert(document.querySelector('.image-container-image').style.backgroundImage.slice(5,-2))
```

```html
<div class='image-container-image' style="background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);"></div>
```

#### 101 bytes alternative

[`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) works, even if the `background-image` exists in an external stylesheet:

```js
alert(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.image-container-image')).backgroundImage.slice(5,-2))
```

```css
.image-container-image{background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);}
```

```html
<div class='image-container-image'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `.style.backgroundImage` on elements. You can use this with the substring function to get the url.

```
st =document.querySelector('.image-container-image').style.backgroundImage;
url = st.substring(5, st.length -2);
```

`url` would become `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg`

EDIT If you want to you can change this to one line of code.

```js
alert(document.querySelector('.image-container-image').style.backgroundImage.substring(5, document.querySelector('.image-container-image').style.backgroundImage.length -2))
```

```html
<div  class='image-container-image' style="background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: Use `.slice(5,-2)`. Saves a lot of bytes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
// Get the image, style and the url from it
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-container-image')[0],
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);

// For IE we need to remove quotes to the proper url
bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");

// Display the url to the user
alert('Image URL: ' + bi);
```

```html
 <div  class='image-container-image' style="background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(document.querySelector('.image-container-image').style.backgroundImage.toString().replace(/(url|\(|\)|")/g, ''))
```

```html
<div  class='image-container-image' style="background-image:url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2h9xCStgaCM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAhjs/TNS6opAJ52g/photo.jpg);">
</div>
```