# How can I hide or remove div width and height if div background-image did not display

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div I would like to remove the width and height if the `background-image` used on that div did not show

Below is my code for the background image

```html
<div id="loaderimage" style="background-image: url(domain.com/'.str_replace(' ', '%20',$firstImage).'); border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden;min-height:100%;width: 100%;padding-top:50%;box-shadow: background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-position: center !important;background-size: cover">;
```

The expected result is to hide/remove div or div width and height if the background image did not return any image

Comment: The <div id="loaderimage"> was echo from the PHP while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use  multiple background:

background-image: url('http://1stimg.jpg'), url('http://2ndimg.jpg');

If the first not load fallback with the second.

Comment: that is not what i want. If the first did not load, div should display none

Comment: For what you want you need to check image with Ajax if error is returned change the display of the div. better if you can check directly in backend before the page rendering

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
let bg = $('#loaderimage').css('background-image');
    let imgPath = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
    console.log(imgPath);
    if(imgPath ==''){
    $('#loaderimage').hide();
    }
```

PHP

```
 <?php

if(!empty(trim($firstImage)) ){ ?> // add your condition here 

    <div id="loaderimage" style="background-image: url(domain.com/'.str_replace(' ', '%20',$firstImage).'); border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden;min-height:100%;width: 100%;padding-top:50%;box-shadow: background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-position: center !important;background-size: cover">;

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: How can I achieve this inside a PHP while loop because the div ('#loaderimage') was echo from the PHP While loop. should I loop the script too with js for loop

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things and come up to [MDN Image()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) class.

As @red said either we can use Ajax for check image or need to use `Image()` class.

I have created one class that check image load or not by built in methods from `Image()` class.

**Example**

```js
class validateImage extends Image {
   constructor(elementId) {
       super(elementId);
       this.getImageBackground(elementId);
  }

  getImageBackground(elementId) {
      this.elementId     = elementId;
      this.image           = document.getElementById(this.elementId);
      this.style           = this.image.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(this.image, false);
      this.backgroundImage = this.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/['"]/g, "");
      super.src            = this.backgroundImage;
  }

  validate() {
      super.onerror = function() {
          this.removeArea();
      }
  }

  removeArea() {
      this.image.style.height = "0px";
      this.image.style.width  = "0px";
      this.image.style.paddingTop = "0px";
  }
}
// Invalid Image.
var validate = new validateImage("loaderimage");
validate.validate();
// Valid Image.
var validate1 = new validateImage("loaderImageValid");
validate1.validate();
```

```html
<div id="loaderimage" style="background-image: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.pngs); border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden;min-height:100%;width: 100%;padding-top:50%;box-shadow: background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-position: center !important;background-size: cover"></div>
<div>
    Test Second Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Third Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Fourth Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Fifth Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Six Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Seven Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Eight Div.
</div>
<div>
    Test Nine Div.
</div>
<div id="loaderImageValid" style="background-image: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png); border-radius:3px;overflow:hidden;min-height:100%;width: 100%;padding-top:50%;box-shadow: background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-position: center !important;background-size: cover"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/7a0dx8th/102/).

This class check image loaded or not and if found any errors then it will remove div's `height`, `width` and `padding-top`.

**References**

[Check if image exists on server using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18837813/6656706)

[Javascript: Get background-image URL of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013171/6656706)