# why backgroundimage is not cssImageValue in chrome? how can i use canvas deal with background-image but not make a new image?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, cssom

base on this article:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSImageValue

```js
const allComputedStyles = button.computedStyleMap(); 
// Return the CSSImageValue Example 
console.log( allComputedStyles.get('background-image') );
```

but in chrome:

```js
var img=imgelement.computedStyleMap().get('background-image')
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
//output: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'
//: The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue ....
```

I want to use canvas check a background-picture is black, but in chrome, how can i do it.

btw, I didnot want to build a new image tag with the background image's url. please give me a more direct way.

Comment: Works here in Chrome 81: https://jsfiddle.net/ra5k6283/1/

Comment: thank you very much, i will learn it :)

Comment: so strange, it is same code, but it is right. and I find my code can run right, maybe chrome fix a bug in these day?

Comment: it is can not run now @Kaiido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last update, finally, i  found out the truth, because there are more than one value with background-image:

```css
//here is cssstylevalue
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)), url("http://localhost:8080/icons/we-flow.png");

//here is cssimagevalue
background-image: url("http://localhost:8080/icons/we-flow.png");
```

Comment: @Kaiido you mean the first sample that background-image with two value is still cssimagevalue? in my chrome 83, it is cssstylevalue.

Answer (score 0):

`CSSImageValue` is still experimental and subject to change. It's not widely supported, and only gained Chrome support in version 66. I'd suggest not using the feature if you're not shimming it for unsupported browsers, or building an experimental web project.

Read this part of the docs for compatibility info.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSImageValue#Browser_compatibility

For accessing this property a different way, try the method in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013171/6632744):

> ```
> var img = document.getElementById('your_div_id'),
> style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
> bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
> ```

Comment: chrome 66 means only 66, not from 66?    get the url then build  image, then use canvas check color, is this you mean?

Comment: the code only get url, and the regex is wrong btw. because background-image with multi-layer. the most important is url string is not cssimagevalue, that can not be use by canvas directly.