# How to retrieve the url from background image using Selenium and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve the url from an background image with Xpath or Javascript, but with no luck for now.
this is what I have

```
<div style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
 <div tws-article-images-preload="item" class="tws-article-images--preload ng-scope tws-article-images-- 
   image-small" ng-click="closeImage()" use-original="useOriginal" style="background-image: 
   url(&quot;https://i.pinimg.com/originals/59/54/b4/5954b408c66525ad932faa693a647e3f.jpg;);">
 </div>
</div>
```

And have tried this two with different modification

```
//*[starts-with(@style, 'background-image: url()] <--Did not work 

return document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload ng-scope tws-article-images--image-small').src
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get background image URL of an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013131/how-to-get-background-image-url-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Why is this tagged with f#? (I'll remove it, it doesn't seem to apply)

Comment: Why is this tagged with "canopy" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried this earlier, but it gives me  Cannot read property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

Comment: @Dymond I edited my answer. Need to get the first item ([0]).

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
return document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload ng-scope tws-article-images--image-small').style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression is wrong (missing `'` and a possible annoying `CRLF`). Fix it with :

```
//*[starts-with(@style, 'background-image:')]/@style
```

Then use regex to clean the result :

```
txt = 'background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/59/54/b4/5954b408c66525ad932faa693a647e3f.jpg;);'
result = re.sub(r"^.+\"(.+?);.+", r"\1", txt)
print(result)
```

With XPath :

```
substring-after(substring-before(//*[starts-with(@style, 'background-image:')]/@style,';)'),'"')
```

Output : `https://i.pinimg.com/originals/59/54/b4/5954b408c66525ad932faa693a647e3f.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the url from the background image you can usethe following solution:

- Using `slice()`:

  ```
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload')[0],
  style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
  bgImage = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
  //printing the url
  console.log('Image URL: ' + bgImage);
  ```
- Using *regex*:

  ```
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName('tws-article-images--preload')[0],
  style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
  var url = backgroundImage.match(/url\(["']?([^"']*)["']?\)/)[1];
  //printing the url
  console.log('Image URL: ' + url);
  ```