# Load same image new on hover state

Tags: css, hover, animated-gif

I have a gif animation of a logo that shows the animation once when you open the website.
Now it should load that same gif again when you hover over it, making it animate again (the gif itself has just one animation cycle).

```
#logo a.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    background-image: url("../img/uf_logo_animation.gif");
    background-size: 115px 115px;
    background-position: 0px 0px ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#logo a.logo:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/uf_logo_animation.gif");
}
```

That code doesn't work - it doesn't make the animation play again. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086744/3623608. Have a look on the solutions listed there.

Comment: Javascript can do something.Remove and reattach it to dom. Maybe the effects wouldn't be noted by the user.