# make animated gif that loops only once loop again

Tags: image, loops, animation

I have a trigger that changes the background of a div to an animated gif
I would like the javascript to force the image to animate again every time it is set as the background, however it currently only loops once and then displays the last frame after that.

Any ideas?

I tried adding ?v=1 but it seems that that causes a delay as the image loads again.  I would prefer to have the image saved in cache but trigger the animation to restart

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568855/restart-animated-gif-as-background-image
It explains how to solve your issue